# Search between dates (date as VARCHAR)

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

I have several dates stored as varchar in the following format: 01-01-2012

I want to search between dates, but sadly it isn't working as I expected. I looked for other threads which have the same question (kinda), but the answers provided there didn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
$fromday = $_POST['fromday'];
$frommonth = $_POST['frommonth'];
$fromyear = $_POST['fromyear'];

$tillday = $_POST['tillday'];
$tillmonth = $_POST['tillmonth'];
$tillyear = $_POST['tillyear'];

$vanaf = "$fromday-$frommonth-$fromyear";
$tot = "$tillday-$tillmonth-$tillyear";

// zoeken
$sel = "SELECT * FROM bestelling WHERE verzenddatum >= '$vanaf' AND verzenddatum <= '$tot'";
$dosel = mysql_query($sel) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dosel))
{
    $datum = $row['verzenddatum'];

    echo $datum;
}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Why aren't you storing them as `DATE` types? If they're already valid dates, then you can alter the schema to use `DATE` or `DATETIME`. It'll make your life much, much easier.

Comment: What isn't working? Is it picking up dates that it shouldn't in the search? Is it not doing anything at all?

Comment: It is not doing anything at all.

Comment: You need to store your dates as any type of number/integer to be able to search based on GT/LT values.

Comment: What do your dates look like?

Comment: As others already stated, `varchar` is not a good idea for dates.

Comment: My dates look like: 01-01-2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not returning any rows because the query is not doing the comparison on valid `DATE` or `DATETIME` fields. You should be storing the dates as a `DATE` type, but what you could do is this:

```
// Switch the order of date elements:
$vanaf = mysql_real_escape_string("$fromyear-$frommonth-$fromday");
$tot = mysql_real_escape_string("$tillyear-$tillmonth-$tillday");

$sel = "SELECT * FROM bestelling WHERE STR_TO_DATE(verzenddatum, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '$vanaf' AND 'tot'";
```

The `mysql_real_escape_string()` function simply reduces the risk of SQL injection, which is what your original code was vulnerable to.

The MySQL function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) converts a string to a valid MySQL`DATE` type. `%d-%m-%Y` is the format you have in your varchar string currently, but `STR_TO_DATE` converts it to `'%Y-%m-%d'` which MySQL can then use to make range comparisons.

Also, I'm using the `BETWEEN` syntax in the SQL as it is the same thing as `val >= val1 AND val <= val2`. It's just clearer and simpler: `val BETWEEN val1 AND val2`.

Comment: Hey that worked! Could you explain the code a bit more so that I fully understand what it's doing?

Comment: @Andre he converts the date in the database to a valid date type for each row and compares that to `$vanaf` and `tot`. Although this works, it will eventually show down because every query needs to convert `verzenddatum` on every single row to make the comparison. If you have a million rows, thats a million conversions every time this query is run. changing the column to `DATE` or `DATETIME` can index the column making it faster/easier on the database.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the dates as either `DATE` field types or `DATETIME` field types. Migrate your database with a script (shouldn't be too hard on a small DB: Backup your table, convert all of your dates to the proper format, change the schema and then re-insert your data. Restore your backup if it explodes.) After fixing this, everything will work as expected.

Comment: Well, I have several other scripts that use this database so I guess my whole site won't work if I change the type, because the insertion is disrupted then.

Comment: Then you'll need to pull all of the rows ignoring the date conditions, parse the dates in PHP and then sort them within PHP (which is a terrible idea). Why did you store your dates like that to start with?

Answer (score 1):

I would **strongly** recommend that you fix this by converting the fields to proper `DATE` fields now and take the pain, rather than waiting until the inevitable performance problems that this approach will incur arise. If you cannot, try this:

```
$fromday = $_POST['fromday'];
$frommonth = $_POST['frommonth'];
$fromyear = $_POST['fromyear'];

$tillday = $_POST['tillday'];
$tillmonth = $_POST['tillmonth'];
$tillyear = $_POST['tillyear'];

$sel = "SELECT * FROM bestelling WHERE SUBSTRING(verzenddatum, 7, 4) BETWEEN '$fromyear' AND '$tillyear' AND SUBSTRING(verzenddatum, 4, 2) BETWEEN '$frommonth' AND '$tillmonth' AND SUBSTRING(verzenddatum, 1, 2) BETWEEN '$fromday' AND '$tillday';"
```

(The hope here is that if a record's date lies outside the "from year" and "to year", the MySQL query optimiser will notice this and bail out early)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's standard date format is 'year-month-day' try this `$vanaf = "$fromyear-$frommonth-$fromday";` and do the same for `$tot`. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: If you store them as day/month/year, then you won't filter correctly just by string comparison. For example, 22-01-1990 will be considered sooner than 15-01-2012 because the 22 is a larger number at the beginning of the string. Either change your date string format or just use the built in date types.

Answer (score 0):

Some theory:

```
$startdate = sprinf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day);
$enddate = sprinf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day);

$query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE date BETWEEN '{$startdate}' AND '{$enddate}'";
```

My tipp: Invest some time in PDO and prepared statements. Dont use mysql_ functions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP, you can set your data type in MySQL to `INT` (Integer) and use UNIX Timestamps for your dates. This is a good way to search for greater than and less than values.

You can use something like:

```
$fromday = strtotime($_POST['fromday']);
```

Comment: Why would you use INT when you can use the _native_ DATE type?

Comment: @David The OP's dates are formatted `MM-DD-YYY`. It is easier (in PHP) to convert `MM-DD-YYYY` to a timestamp that it is to convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD`. Though I do agree native types are always better to use.

Comment: Not really, considering it takes one line either way: `echo new \DateTime($oldDate)->format('Y-m-d');` @MBJ

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Only Mysql query it's Working.

select * from Your_table_name
where STR_TO_DATE(  "your_date_field" ,  '%d/%m/%Y' )
BETWEEN  STR_TO_DATE("your_first_date", '%d/%m/%Y')
AND  STR_TO_DATE("your_second_date", '%d/%m/%Y')
```